# Overriding Array.of() in Typescript for a custom 2D array class that extends Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, inheritance, multidimensional-array, types

I'm trying to extend Array and make an Array2D class. I want the constructor to take in any number of arguments, but these arguments should be Arrays of type T. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Array2D<T> extends Array<T[]> {
  constructor(...args: T[][]) {
    super(...args)
  }

  static of(...args: T[][]) {
    return new Array2D(...args)
  }
}
```

Typescript is showing this error:

```
Types of property 'of' are incompatible.
    Type '<T>(...args: T[][]) => Array2D<T>' is not assignable to type '<T>(...items: T[]) => T[]'.
      Types of parameters 'args' and 'items' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
```

Can someone explain what Tyspecript is complaining about and how to fix this.

Comment: My guess is that subclassing is intentionally made unsound for constructors, but other static functions are strict.  So `Array2D.of()` had better accept the same arguments as `Array.of()`, but it doesn't.  So you get an error.  The workarounds for this are numerous, but presumably the easiest is to just change the name of `of` to `Array2D.make()` or something at doesn't conflict.

Comment: @jcalz The problem with that, unless I'm mistaken, is that Array2D.of() will still exist but won't enforce typing properly, it will allow the creation of 1D arrays.

Comment: A simple workaround is to forego inheriting the Array, and just make a new class. Having tried similar things in the past, I've always come to the conclusion that, even though there's a little extra work involved, it is much easier, additionally giving the peace of mind that your code works as intended. With your particular example, `[...new Array2D([1,2,3])]` will give you a `number[][]`, which is not what you want, I presume. There might be other similar quirks, which making your own class will allow you to avoid.

Comment: @BijouTrouvaille Actually that is precisely the behaviour that I want. The reason I really wanted to extend Array was because I wanted to be able to use the `myVar[y][x]` syntax to access items in the array instead of having to implement methods to do so. But if I can't find a workaround I guess that's what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: @neoflash have you considered [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#User-defined_iterables)?

Comment: @BijouTrouvaille Not really. I mean, if was going to have to make a class that doesn't inherit from Array, I would implement [Symbol.iterator] so that you can at least iterate over it. But other than that, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another typing workaround.  Let's widen the type of the `Array` constuctor to something with no known static methods:

```
const VanillaArrayConstructor: new <T>(...args: T[]) => Array<T>
    = Array;
```

You can use `VanillaArrayConstructor` to construct arrays, but the compiler will complain if you try to call `.from()` or `.of()` or any other static methods.  And then you can extend *that* instead of `Array`:

```
class Array2D<T> extends VanillaArrayConstructor<T[]> {
    constructor(...args: T[][]) {
        super(...args)
    }

    static of<T>(...args: T[][]) {
        return new Array2D(...args)
    }
}
```

This makes no difference to the actual behavior of `Array2D` at runtime, but the typing is now such that the compiler has no expectation that the type of the `Array2D` constructor extends the type of the `Array` constructor.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAagQzASwDaoQQQE7YQTwGFxpsBXYKEbALhjAFMB3GAHgBUA+ACgDp+E2AOYQ67ANoBdAJQwAvJxg48+DorlLcBANwAoXcAwQImlQCYAImpgMAHlAZgAJicQp0WLURJRylahxSigDeujAwoJC+FFTYfALCojASklKyoeHhEGQADgxx-LyCItJ64QC++llQCFDIwDAgAGZq8UWJYlJpMBmZ2AxQZNhg9MymBJZtxRClYTCVlUA)